# How if statement work in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

This code find the maximum element of a dynamic array

```
int i, n, *x, max;
    cout << "eneter a number: ";
    cin  >> n;
    x = new int[n];
    max = x[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] > max)
            {
            max  = x[i];
            }
    }
    cout << max << endl;

    delete []x;
```

Let's assume my input be :

```
    n=4
   {3, 22, 15, 17}
```

So the output is `22`

I don't understand how if select the `22` as `max`.

This is my understanding of how it works:

```
n=4
{3, 22, 15, 17}

x[0] = 3 
first loop i=0 -> x[0]>x[0] false

x[1] = 22
second  loop i=1 -> x[1]>x[0] true

x[2] = 15
third loop i=2 -> x[2]>x[0] true

x[3] = 17
forth loop i=3 -> x[3]>x[0] true
```

I know I'm wrong but as my assumption the 17 must be the maximun value.
What am I missing here?

This is all my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


    int i, n, *x, sum=0, location, max;
    cout << "eneter a number: ";
    cin  >> n;
    x = new int[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){

        cin >> x[i];

}
    cout << endl<< x[0];
    max = x[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] > max)
            {
            max  = x[i];
            location = i+1;
            }
    }
    cout << endl<< max;

    delete []x;


}
```

Comment: You do *initialize* the array somewhere, don't you? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: instead of `if (x[i] > x[0])`, it should be `if (x[i] > max)`. Also, your array is never initialized.

Comment: I know, it works by both, but how it selects the 22?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It has been initilalized dynamicly by pointer.

Comment: ebrahimhadi , The code you have, will select 17 for `max`, provided that you take input using the `cin` for the array too, Are you sure you've used `if (x[i] > x[0])` and not `if (x[i] > max)` as @zahirdhada suggests?

Comment: Please show us the code part where you have initialized or filled the array

Comment: Yes you are tue. but with if (x[i] > max) how it select 22 as my assumption?

Comment: @ebrahimhadi, Your program's behavior is undefined, as your array is never initialized, but supposing you initialize it with `{3, 22, 15, 17}`, the output will be `17`, NOT `22`.

Comment: I've edited already, lets see agian

Comment: @ebrahimhadi, You're still not initializing your array.

Comment: Check agian I added the array initilazation

Comment: @ebrahimhadi, Now the output will be 17 because of the `if (x[i] > x[0])`. If it were `if (x[i] > max)` instead, the output would be 22.

Comment: @zahirdhada Yes I missed that part, I've edited, but how it selects 22 while in the third loop max=x[0] is smaller than 17....?

Comment: I think that got the point, after each loop the max will be *(x+i), right???

Comment: @ebrahimhadi ‘*third loop max=x[0] is smaller than 17*’ `max` only gets set to `x[0]` *once*, *before* the loop.

Comment: @ebrahimhadi, checkout Vlad from Moscow's answer,it's explained very well.

Comment: I think your first code was differant

Comment: @Vagish Yes I missed to change this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522641/how-if-statement-work-in-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment49119701_30522641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this step

```
x[1] = 22
second  loop i=1 -> x[1]>x[0] true
```

as the value of the condition of the if statement is `true` then the substatement of the if statement is executed

```
if (x[i] > max)
{
    max  = x[i];
}
```

and max is set to 22.

```
    max  = x[i];
```

In the following steps there is compared x[i] with the new max. So instead of

```
x[2] = 15
third loop i=2 -> x[2]>x[0] true

x[3] = 17
forth loop i=3 -> x[3]>x[0] true
```

it will be correctly to write

```
x[2] = 15
third loop i=2 -> x[2]>max false

x[3] = 17
forth loop i=3 -> x[3]>max false
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in header `<algorithm>` that does in fact the same. You could call it the following way

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int *max = std::max_element( x, x + n );

std::cout << "max = " << *max << std::endl;
```